# Dynamic Pivot Error in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I used the above code from the link. But I recieve an error as

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The column 'Factory' was
>   specified multiple times for 'p'

[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Here is my table :

**TEST**

```
ID      score    Check      TotalofScore
------  -----    -------    ------------
867439  1        factory        1
867439  1        Plant          1
867442  1        factory        1
867442  1        Plant          1
923991  1        Warehouse      1
923991  1        Plant          1
923930  1        factory        1
923930  1        Plant          1
923101  1        Warehouse      1
923101  1        Plant          1
```

Here's my try

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename([check])
                      FROM   TEST
                      GROUP  BY [Check],
                                [ID]
                      ORDER  BY [ID]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (SELECT TEST.[ID],
                     Score,
                     [check],
                     [Total Of Score] = Count(TEST.Score) over(partition by [ID], [score], [check])
             FROM TEST) T
            pivot 
            (
             SUM (T.[score])
             for T.[check] in (' + @cols + N') ) p '

EXEC Sp_executesql @query;
```

Expected Result :

```
ID       TotalofScore   factory     Plant   Warehouse
------   ------------   -------     -----   ---------
867439      1             1 
867439      1                                   1
867442      1                       1
867442      1                                   1
923991      1             1 
923991      1             1
923930      1                       1
923930      1                       1
923101      1              1
923101      1                                   1
```

Comment: @Bluefeet This was the one I wanted help on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in Error You cannot specify same column name more than once in `Pivot` like

`..pivot (SUM (T.[score])
      for T.[check] in ([factory,[Plant],[factory]..))p`

Change your `@cols` initialization like this

```
SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename([check])
                      FROM   TEST
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Or

```
SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename([check])
                      FROM   TEST
                      GROUP  BY [Check]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

**Update :** To convert the Dynamic Pivot into procedure and insert the result into new table

```
create procedure dbname.schemaname.DynamicPivotProcedure 
as
begin
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename([check])
                      FROM   TEST
                      GROUP  BY [Check]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = N'SELECT ID, [Total Of Score],' + @cols + N' from 
             (SELECT TEST.[ID],
                     Score,
                     [check],
                     [Total Of Score] = Count(TEST.Score) over(partition by [ID], [score], [check])
             FROM TEST) T
            pivot 
            (
             SUM (T.[score])
             for T.[check] in (' + @cols + N') ) p '

EXEC Sp_executesql @query; 
end

go
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL 
begin
DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
end

SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM 
OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2008;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC dbname.schemaname.DynamicPivotProcedure')

SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable
```

Comment: SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT ',' + Quotename([check])
                      FROM   TEST
                      GROUP  BY [Check] , [ID]
                      ORDER  BY [ID]
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

Comment: @Lewan - Mybad forgot remove Id from order by, updated check now

Comment: It did the trick, Is there way I could do the same task in a view. This is dynamic sql I know it can't be used in a view. But is there an alternative way to do the same task

Comment: @Lewan - If know values in `Check` column then change it to static pivot

Comment: Yes that could be one way but then I will have columns with null values which I don't want .

Comment: @Lewan - You are talking about Which column

Comment: The "Check" Column. The values are loaded based on business check n it keeps changing. If I do it in a static way then I would have the columns transposed with null values if they are not in the Test table.

Comment: @Lewan - Then you can change this Dynamic Pivot query to `SP`

Comment: Could I use the same query to SP where I could load the results to a table ?

Comment: @Lewan Yes you can check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table

Comment: I need to load the contents into a table. So I could use Insert Table Execute Resulttable. But then since this is monthly task. The table must either emptied or dropped and recreated.

Comment: @Lewan Use `If exists` to drop and recreate table and i doubt that you can use `Insert Table Execute Resulttable` method because you are unaware of the result table column list since it is Dynamic Pivot. I would Suggest you to use `OpenRowset method`

Comment: **OpenRowset** is something new for me. Can I use the code in this way. 'CREATE PROC TESTRESULTS
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM sys.databases
END
GO
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #MyTable FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local)\SQL2012;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
     'EXEC MYPIVOT')'

Comment: @Lewan - Updated my answer try that

Comment: **OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.".
Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].**

Comment: My Server is 2012 , should there be any changes in the connection property.

Comment: @Lewan - even am not sure about the error. Give me sometime

Comment: @Lewan replace ` (local)\SQL2012` with `select @@SERVERNAME` result and check my answer

Comment: @Lewan replace `(local)\SQL2012` with `select @@SERVERNAME` result and change `exec DynamicPivotProcedure` to `exec databasename.schemaname.DynamicPivotProcedure`

Comment: I tried as you said , I still get the same error but the last part of the error says this **"Msg 53, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. "**

Comment: @Lewan - ask this as new question am sure there is something wrong with your connection string on openrowset for me it is working

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Id` from `GROUP BY` and `ORDER By` clause. So that you get the `DISTINCT` Check columns.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([check]) 
  from #Sample
  group by [Check]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = N'SELECT  ID, [Total Of Score], ' + @cols + N'  from 
             (
               SELECT 
TEST.[ID],
Score,
[check],
[Total Of Score] = Count(TEST.Score) over(partition by [ID], [score], [check])
FROM #Sample AS TEST
  ) T
  pivot 
  (
     SUM (T.[score])
      for T.[check] in (' + @cols + N')
  ) p '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: This works but I miss the ID and TotalOfScore column ,

Comment: @Lewan: Add the columns in select list. Use the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. 'I was assuming ' + cols + N' does the trick since the sub select query has the columns mentioned in it. I know this can not be used in a view. But is there an alternative to doing the same task in a view. Since dynamic sql is not often recommended.